# Use of jQuery in mobile view what should be the number of jQuery libraries should I use?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am building a website in ROR and for mobile view I am using mobile_fu gem.

In my mobile view designer have provided me a design which contains a lot of use of jQuery sliders, jQuery player, Image sliders, drop down menu, cursors etc.

So I to implement all of them by using jQuery plugins available on internet. But now my project contains 7 jQuery libraries apart from the default jQuery and still I think this number will increase.

But now I am worry about user from mobile devise user will have to wait for a very log time to page get loaded.

Can any body tell me what should be the minimum or maximum number of jQuery plugins should be used in our mobile view if user is using simple gprs 2G network or low bandwidth and from a high bandwidth like wifi.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hard and fast rule on how many libraries you must have. But thinking of your situation where users have only 2G connection, seven plugins would be bit heavy for the data connection speed.

If users have 3G access or 4G access you can go for seven plug-ins as there are not much problem. But again remember entry level devices and mid range devices will have lack of processing power problem.

Alternatively think of [techniques such as caching](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) your jQuery framework, plugin, other JS files locally using cache manifest. This will enable users to download the files one time and next time files will be taken from phone’s cache storage.